# FluentValidation 6.4.0-beta* Nuget Package restore failed, operation timed out

Tags: asp.net-core, fluentvalidation, nuget-package-restore

I was trying to add FluentValidation to my asp.net core project. 
Originally i want to use [Nuget FluentValidation.AspNetCore/6.4.0-beta9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation.AspNetCore/6.4.0-beta9) and this pakage depends on [Nuget FluentValidation/6.4.0-beta9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation/6.4.0-beta9). So I added the FluentValidation to project.json.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    ...,
    "FluentValidation": "6.4.0-beta9"
  },
  ....
}
```

This results in a package restore failed Message with following Output.

```
log  : Restoring packages for C:\Users\asdf\devel\BTnetCorePoc\NcCqrsPoc\src\NcCqrsPos.Web.Commands\project.json...
log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://10.0.10.49/NugetServer/nuget_error/FindPackagesById()?id='FluentValidation''.
log  : An error occurred while sending the request.
log  :   The operation timed out
log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://10.0.10.49/NugetServer/nuget_error/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Text.RegularExpressions''.
log  : An error occurred while sending the request.
log  :   The operation timed out
....
error: Failed to retrieve information from remote source 'http://10.0.10.49/NugetServer/nuget_error/FindPackagesById()?id='FluentValidation''.
error: An error occurred while sending the request.
error: Failed to retrieve information from remote source 'http://10.0.10.49/NugetServer/nuget_error/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Text.RegularExpressions''.
error: An error occurred while sending the request.
```

So it results in any kind of TimeOut, i not really well understand how nuget package publishing works. Timeout seems to me there are a server not available or sth like that, but the nuget package page linked above worked well (*but i think that is just an indices page*). And that ip 10.0.10.49 seems to be wierd ip for restoring a package. Does I probably missconfigured any nuget source path in vs Studio? (that throws me in mind while writing this question, i will check that later)

To use FluentValidation.AspNetCore, I need at least the version of FluentValidation 6.4.0-beta1. So i tried the most versions for
FluentValidation 6.4.0-beta1 *to* FluentValidation 6.4.0-beta9 *(which i targeted)*
and every try failes with the same timeout error *(becuz of timeout it takes some minutes, i dont know how to hard stop, the restoring process)*

After that i was trying to restore earlier Versions of FluentValidation *which i cant use (FluentValidation.AspNetCore needs at least FluentValiedation 6.4.0-beta1)*, i checked if nuget restore works with older and stable FluentValidation. I tried following versions:

FluentValidation 6.2.1 *(latest stable)* 
FluentValidation 6.2.1-beta1
FluentValidation 6.3.3-alpha
FluentValidation 6.3.4-alpha

Restoring these Versions works well so i think the error could not be any kind of missconfigured VS on my Machine. So where could be the Problem else? And what should be my next steps? I created an [FluentValidation Github Repo Issue](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/378) after this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like JeremySkinner suggested in the [FluentValidation Github Issue](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/378). I removed the additional configured Package Source, configured in VS2015 (Tools->Options->Nuget Packager Manager->Packager Sources: **deactivate my addidional custom 10.0.10.49/NugetServer**->OK)
**Trying now to restore** FluentValidation 6.4.0-beta9 **works well**.

So there is a strange behavior which i cant figure out why this issue happening when additional Package Sources is defined. I just keep that in mind. I dont need that additional Package Source, so just deactivate it,  works for that issue.